# Find the 1 meter distance through lat and lon in android

Tags: android, location

Actually I want that when 1 meter covered by the device a toast notification appears and it shows One meter has been covered.Similarly when again one meter will be cover the toast notification again appears.This phenomena continues further.Please help me to sort out the problem.Please provide me a sample code to do that...Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points)

Comment: The answer of your question is in this SO thread.

Answer (score 2):

There is no location technology with one-meter resolution available to Android devices. Hence, what you want is not possible, sorry.